# C - HashMap Values() function - Do I return NULL values?

Tags: c, null, hashmap

I'm making a HashMap in C and I'm trying to make a Values() function which is standard in all HashMaps.

[for example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values())

Let's say my HashMap looked like the following:

(Note the key set is of type `<void*, void*>`)

```
// CAPACITY = 8, SIZE = 4
[0] <"Pancakes", 24>
[1] = NULL
[2] = <"Waffles", 7>
[3] = NULL
[4] = NULL
[5] = NULL
[6] = <"Eggs", 12>
[7] = <"Bacon", 99>
```

Normally, in this sitatuion, I would create an array of `size_t` `5`, and it would look like the following.

```
{ 24, 7, 12, 99, NULL }
```

NULL must be here or else after I return the array, the loop that attempts to go through the array will not be able to know when to stop.

What if I had the following though?

```
// CAPACITY = 8, SIZE = 4
[0] <"Pancakes", 24>
[1] = NULL
[2] = <"Waffles", NULL>
[3] = NULL
[4] = NULL
[5] = NULL
[6] = <"Eggs", 12>
[7] = <"Bacon", 99>
```

Suddenly, my array looks like the following:

```
{ 24, NULL, 12, 99, NULL }
```

And when I would attempt to print that out after it was returned, it would print the following:

```
24
```

How should I handle this problem? Should I just ignore `NULL` values? If so, my `HashMap` might have a `size` of 4 and the programmer is expecting `4` values from my `Values()` function, and yet I am only giving him an array of size `3`. And no, I really don't want to make a `struct` in order to pass multiple variables back *such as `size` AND the array*

Comment: Your question is not clear. `<"Waffles", NULL>` That is not valid C code so it is not clear what you are trying to represent there. What is that `NULL` supposed to represent? And what is that array supposed to be for that you keep referring to. It's really not clear what your idea of a HashMap implementation is. A [mcve] would probably clarify things.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a hash map in the sense that you're listing the values in sequential order and a hash map doesn't necessarily do that. You can't assume the values will be in consecutive slots in the table.

Comment: Let me clarify. The above code is not valid C code on purpose. I didn't want to complicate things with irrelevant code. Instead I wanted to describe a theoretical problem. <"Bacon", 99> is a `struct Node` which has two `void*` fields. This means my `key` or `value` can be `NULL` which is acceptable in a `HashMap` but not a `HashTable`. Hopefully that clears up all concerns.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it so there should be no more confusion.

Comment: What is that array supposed to be for? You seem to have some ideas which you think are standard implementation but I don't think it is.

Comment: @2501 All `HashMap` implementations have a `Values()` function which is supposed to `return` an array of all `Values` in the entire `HashMap`. I am asking how to do that when I encounter `NULL` in the `value` element of a `KeySet`.

Comment: One option is to use a different sentinel. Something that is outside the value set. If possible. (Suggestion: update your question to say that the array is the set of values being returned....that isn't clear the way your question is currently worded).

Comment: Because in the second example, there is a `NULL` value for one of the `value` elements in the `KeySet`. Why is that a problem? Well, if I add `NULL` into the array that I will `return` when the function ends, that means my array is now **NULL terminated** and when I go to iterate through the array later, the array will appear **smaller** than it really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I'm just going to return `<Key, Value> Nodes` instead of just `Keys` or `Values`. In my program, I won't have to deal with `NULL` `Nodes` so I avoid the problem of `NULL` `Keys` and `Values` completely. If I had to go with one of the suggested methods, I would use Kaylum's suggestion.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for returning arrays of different size to callers, apart from returning a `struct`:

- **Have the caller pass you an array and a max size, and return `size_t`** - this option requires the caller to allocate the array, which may be done statically.
- **Pass a pointer to the return array, and return the size** - This requires the caller to deallocate the array returned from your function.
- **You could return a `NULL`-terminated array** - this approach also requires the caller to free the result, but there is no need to return the size.

Returning `NULL`s inside the data, and instructing the caller to skip over them, is a very confusing choice which does not give you anything in return: you are still required to tell the caller how big the returned array is, and the `NULL`-termination option is out.

Comment: Man I really wanted to not have any parameters for this function besides the `HashMap`. I guess I can't really have it all? Clearly though method number 2 won't work right?

Comment: @Hatefiend returning a `NULL`-terminated array lets you have a function with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a sentinel value that will never be part of the value set. For example, instead of `NULL`, declare a dummy variable (of any type) and use its address as the sentinel value:

```
int dummy;
void *sentinel = &dummy;
```

And an example value array would be:

```
{ 24, NULL, 12, 99, sentinel }
```

The `sentinel` value is then part of the API exported by the HashMap implementation and client code would check for that value to determine the end of the value array.

Comment: I feel like making the programmer who uses my hash map having to use 'sentinel' is a rather huge sacrifice. Do other languages even include NULL values when returning 'Values ()'?

Comment: How is it a huge sacrifice? Instead of telling the user that `NULL` indicates the end of array you tell them that it is `sentinel`. Just like some standard file functions use a special `EOF` value. If you don't like that then your other alternative is to pass an explicit size (which you seem also not to like). Makes it hard to answer your question if you don't state what you consider to be acceptable or unacceptable. But those are the two main options - size or sentinel.

Comment: @Hatefiend I guess another alternative is to have the size as the first element in the values array. Not as clean as the other alternatives in my opinion but it'll work.